# compare datetime (minutes) in php?

Tags: php, datetime

I'm trying to compare two different `new DateTime` by minutes but I have no luck with it!

one is the end date which is in the future and the other one is the end date + 10 minutes.

so when the end date is smaller than the one with 10 minutes added, i need to do something and if the end date is still greater than the one with 10 minutes added, i need to run my code as usual.

my current code is this:

```
$end_date = new DateTime('2015-01-21 17:28:23');
$datetime1 = new DateTime();
$datetime2 = new DateTime($end_date);
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$finalDate = $interval->format('%d day %h hours %i minutes %s seconds');

$minutes_to_add = 10;

$time = new DateTime($end_date);
$time->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $minutes_to_add . 'M'));


echo $stamp = $time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo '<br />';
echo $stamp = $datetime2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

if( $time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') < $datetime2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')){
echo("result_messageTi=times up");
}
    }
}else{
echo("result_messageTi=$finalDate");    
}
```

the code above does not compare the two given times at all and in result i get nothing on my php page.

could someone please advise on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't compare the formats, compare the objects : `if( $time < $datetime2){`

Comment: @ojovirtual, I've done that too but I get nothing on my php page at all...

Comment: Turn error reporting on.

Comment: @Glavić, I already have. there is no error at all either!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  compare DateTime objects directly so this should work and I think that extra curly bracket might be causing syntax error and so you are not seeing anything. Try this:

```
if( $time < $datetime2){
    echo("result_messageTi=times up");
}else{
    echo("result_messageTi=$finalDate");    
}
```

Comment: OMG, that extra curly bracket was causing the issue.... I just don't know why the error reporting didn't identify that issue! Thanks a bunch mate

Comment: if there is parse error, you won't be able to change display errors in script, you have to do it in php.ini or htaccess or somewhere else outside the script which has parse error.